# O que são as PEP's no Python?

Tags: python

Eu estava pesquisando a respeito do *Type Hints* no Python e me deparei com essa página.

[PEP 0484 - Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

O que seria essa PEP?

Isso é algum tipo de proposta para as próximas versões das linguagens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PEP's (***Python Enhancement Proposals***, ou **Propostas para Melhoramentos no Python**). Funciona de maneira muito semelhante ao [RFC do IEEE](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) ([inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments)): algum usuário interessado em um melhoramento ou funcionalidade nova detalha para a comunidade o que é este melhoramento/funcionalidade, como ele deve funcionar, uma prova de conceito, o que já foi tentado e funcionou ou não funcionou e até mesmo um código que faça essa implementação.

A comunidade, por sua vez, avalia o *paper* e decide se ele procede ou não para fazer parte da linguagem. Se sim, o recurso novo é liberado nas próximas versões.