# O que são as JEPs no Java?

Tags: java, terminologia

Estava vendo o [backlog do JDK 12](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/12/) e vi que as alterações são todas mencionadas como JEPs. Inclusive, na lista de *features* tem "JEPs visadas para o JDK 12, até então".

Pelo que vi, uma JEP é uma espécie de documento com formato definido.

Então, o que são essas JEPs? Como elas funcionam? Tem algum relacionamento com as [PEPs do Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107719/64969)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JEP é exatamente a mesma coisa que a PEP do Python, realmente só troca a letra, até a definição é a mesma "Java Enhacement Proposal", e o processo de uso é quase idêntico. Claro cada comunidade tem um pouco seu jeito, seu critério do que é bom, de como escrever (como formatar, quais seções, etc.), quem pode participar de que jeito, etc. mas a função é a mesma. Na verdade ele é um processo anterior ao que já existia o [JCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) (Java Community Process) que é o passo final que todo JEP passa se for alterar algo na tecnologia (não conheço os detalhes, mas o que apenas recomenda usuários seguirem, tipo a PEP 8, não vai para o JCP), de qualquer forma é algo mais informal, conforme [mostra a Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Enhancement_Proposal).

O documento é mais visível, mas ambos são um processo, mais que um documento.

O [JEP-1](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/1) explica melhor :P

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).